# What is the difference between bcc32 and bcc32ide in Borland?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

- We find a slight difference in how `bcc32` and `bcc32ide` behave on a
  file.
- `bcc32ide` works and `bcc32` crashes.

Would there be any detrimental side effects to switching to `bcc32ide` for our automated builds?

Also, what is the difference between these two compilers (other than one crashes and one doesn't)?

Comment: The page http://www.codegear.com/downloads/free/cppbuilder shows that the borland compiler is from 2000. That's ancient. Cant you switch to a more modern one (msvc or gcc)?

Comment: Oh yes, it is ancient.  Older than computers, it was used to compile mud into huts in medeval times.  Can't upgrade just now though, we're using a lot of borland propriatary libraries.  @Adrien Bell even if I could it is the compiler itself which is crashing rather than my code.  I just want to know if switching builds to the ide version of the compiler is going to be a terrible idea.

Comment: What version are you using? The 5.5 (free) or BCB5 (paid) versions do not seem to include bcc32ide.exe.  Are you using BCB6? BCB2006?

Answer (score 1):

See *[Re: BCB 6 Compiler slowness and how to speed it up dramatically](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/waArticleBookmark.6088114)* for an explanation.

Quote:

> bcc32ide.exe is a bcc32.exe, but it uses the IDE compiler. For
>   example, some compiler assertions do not raise with the IDE compiler, but
>   with bcc32.exe. So replacing bcc32.exe in makefiles by bcc32ide.exe will
>   allow to compile projects that compile within the IDE, but not at console.
>   
>   bcc32ide.exe also adds some additional parameters: 
>   -automake                     Compile only modified files 
>   -verbose                          Output current compiled line number during compilation 
>   -pch=filename_pch.h     Use advanced precompiled headers 
>   -FIfilename                       Force include (multiple, usage like -Iincludedir) 
>   And it supports multi-process shared access to the advanced PCH file
>   (required for mtbcc32.exe).